# Reverse pyramid java pattern with "!!"

Tags: java

I want to make this pattern:

```
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
\\!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!//
\\\\!!!!!!!!!!!!!!////
\\\\\\!!!!!!!!!!//////
\\\\\\\\!!!!!!////////
\\\\\\\\\\!!//////////
```

How would you go about it?
I first made the left side like this:

```
for (j = 1; j <= i; j++ ){
    System.out.print("\\\\");
}
```

Then I made the right side like this:

```
for (j = 1; j <= i; j++ ){
    System.out.print("//");
}
```

Both for-loops are in a for-loop like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    //input should be customizable, like 4, 6, 8, 43 and so on
    int input = 4;
    for (int i = 0; i < input; i++){

        //left side slashes
        for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++ ){
            System.out.print("\\\\");
        }
        //Here is the problem. It almost works like supposed to, just a on Line 2 appears 1 "!!" to much, then on line 1 there is 2 "!!" too much.
        for (int k = input - i; k > 0; k--){
            for(int l = 0; l < k; l++){
                System.out.print("!!");
            }
        }

        //right side slashes 
        for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++ ){
            System.out.print("//");
        }
        //Line breaks
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you have 2 nested loops to print `!!` (so 3 in total)? That should basically work the same as printing `//` and `\\ `, just with decreasing frequency, so use just 1 loop.

Comment: Please provide us with some sample cases if you have. For some reason, getting patterns of that format seems a little off when compared to the given input of 4 and corresponding output.

Comment: @Thomas You're right... I thought I had to loop once for the length of the !!s and then again for the actual print of the !!s. I'll try one for-loop!

Comment: @Vens8 oh my bad, the input is 6 actually with that output. I'm sorry!

Comment: @thorzos Ahh that makes more sense, cool np

Answer (score 3):

You may use the [repeat method](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#repeat(int)) of class String to simplify the code. Then it's just a matter of counting how many characters you need.

```
public class Pyramid {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int n = 6;
        if (args.length > 0) {
            n = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        }
        
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            System.out.println("\\\\".repeat(i) + "!!".repeat(2 * (n - i) - 1) + "//".repeat(i));
        }
    }
}

java Pyramid

!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
\\!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!//
\\\\!!!!!!!!!!!!!!////
\\\\\\!!!!!!!!!!//////
\\\\\\\\!!!!!!////////
\\\\\\\\\\!!//////////
```

Of course, you can still replace the calls to `repeat` with `for` loops, and you should see the problem now: you don't need two nested loops for the middle `!!` characters.

```
public class Pyramid {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int n = 6;
        if (args.length > 0) {
            n = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        }
 
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {

            // Left side slashes
            for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
                System.out.print("\\\\");
            }
            
            for (int j = 2 * (n - i) - 1; j > 0; j--) {
                System.out.print("!!");
            }

            // Right side slashes 
            for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
                System.out.print("//");
            }

            // Line break
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Elegant answer.

Answer (score 0):

I got it right this time. Thanks a lot @Thomas

```
public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int input = 4;
    for (int i = 0; i < input; i++){
        
        for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++){
            System.out.print("\\\\");
        }
        
        for (int j = (input*2-1) - (2*i); j > 0; j--){
            System.out.print("!!");
        }
        
        for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++){
            System.out.print("//");
        }
        
        System.out.println();
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
    int n = 6;
    for (int i = 0, excl = n * 4 - 2, slash = 0; i < n; ++i, excl -= 4, slash += 2)
        System.out.println("\\".repeat(slash) + "!".repeat(excl) + "/".repeat(slash));
}
```

output:

```
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
\\!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!//
\\\\!!!!!!!!!!!!!!////
\\\\\\!!!!!!!!!!//////
\\\\\\\\!!!!!!////////
\\\\\\\\\\!!//////////
```